# Why does `agile_ref` fail with some objects, such as `CoreWindow`?

Tags: windows, uwp, c++-winrt

C++/WinRT's `agile_ref` supposedly allows usage of non-agile objects in an agile way.
However, I've found that this fails with at least `CoreWindow` instances.

As a short example:

```cpp
void Run()
{
    auto window{ CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread() };
    window.Activate();

    auto agile_wnd{ make_agile(window) };
    ThreadPool::RunAsync([=](const auto&) {
        auto other_wnd{ agile_wnd.get() };
        other_wnd.SetPointerCapture();
    });

    auto dispatcher{ window.Dispatcher() };
    dispatcher.ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessUntilQuit);
}
```

`Run()` is called on the UI thread, then attempts to create an agile reference and then use it to call the `CoreWindow` from the thread pool. However, this fails with `"The application called an interface that was marshaled for a different thread."` Since `agile_ref` uses `RoGetAgileReference` internally to marshal the object, and the calls to create the reference and then unmarshal it are both succeeding, this appears to me to be `CoreWindow` simply refusing to be marshaled at all.

Unless, of course, this is working as intended and the `RoGetAgileReference` call silently fails to marshal the `CoreWindow`.

So what causes the `SetPointerCapture` call to fail, even with the `agile_ref`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is misleading. Most of the Windows.UI classes are actually agile. The challenge is that they perform an explicit thread check to ensure that you are actually calling them from the appropriate UI thread. That's why an agile_ref won't help. The solution is to use the Dispatcher, which gets you on the correct thread. You can then simply call methods on the object directly.